# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.rectangle_1

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm currently developing an Android application on Face recognition. So I obtain a source code from github. It use OpenCv, but the source code using an old version of OpenCv and I'm using the latest version which is 3.0.0. There's no error on the code and it's successfully open the app, but when I point to someone face, it suddenly stopped working.

It gave me an error like this:

```
 Process: com.example.syafiq.test, PID: 3249
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.rectangle_1:(JDDDDDDDDI)V
     at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.rectangle_1(Native Method)
     at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.rectangle(Imgproc.java:2779)
     at com.example.syafiq.test.FdActivity.onCameraFrame(FdActivity.java:431)
     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:393)
     at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:346)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The (Imgproc.java:2779) pointed here:

```
rectangle_1(img.nativeObj, pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, color.val[0], color.val[1], color.val[2], color.val[3], thickness);
```

The (FdActivity.java:431) pointed here:

```
 (line430) for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
 (line431) Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
```

Before this, the source code on (FdActivity.java:431) was Core.rectangle and it's an error, so I've changed it to Imgproc based on the Internet that I've found to fix that code line.

On (CameraBridgeViewBase.java:393) pointed here:

```
(line392) if (mListener != null) {
(line393) modified = mListener.onCameraFrame(frame);
```

On (JavaCameraView.java:346) pointed here:

```
(line345) if (!mFrameChain[1 - mChainIdx].empty())
(line346) deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[1 - mChainIdx]);
```

I'm new to android development and new to OpenCV :/ I appreciate your time and help to consideration to helping me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

I saw this unanswered question yesterday while looking for a resolution to the same answer.  I did not find an answer that seemed to fit my situation. It turns out my solution was quite easy.  I was using example code that was written for OpenCV 2.4 and I had to change from Core.rectangle to ImgProc.rectanle as I am using OpenCV 3.1.  My code and includes were fine but what i missed was my Async Initialization had the wrong version. I needed to update my intialization to the right version.

OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);

That corrected the problem. As your question is 5 months old you have likely moved on but others may see this.